# iptables: "Protocol wrong type for socket"

Tags: iptables

When I run the following command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I get the following error:

```
iptables: Protocol wrong type for socket.
```

I've run the command through `strace` and I can see that it fails on a `setsockopt` call:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)  = 4
fcntl64(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
getsockopt(4, SOL_IP, 0x40 /* IP_??? */, "filter\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., [84]) = 0
getsockopt(4, SOL_IP, 0x41 /* IP_??? */, "filter\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., [12328]) = 0
setsockopt(4, SOL_IP, 0x40 /* IP_??? */, "filter\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 12736) = -1 EPROTOTYPE (Protocol wrong type for socket)
```

What could be going wrong? I suspect it's a missing kernel config option but there's about 50 options relating to netfilter and I don't just want to start turning them on without understanding what I'm doing. Is there a way to figure out what's missing?

**EDIT:** Looks like the call that's failing in iptables is `setsockopt(handle->sockfd, TC_IPPROTO, SO_SET_REPLACE, ...)`.

Comment: How did you get your system into this state?

Comment: @Michael Hampton; It's an embedded system that I've inherited at work and been given the task getting some firewall scripts running on. It starts life as a Gentoo install, gets butchered by some scripts to reduce its size, compressed into a firmware image and installed on a device with 256MB of memory. I need to enable netfilter and install iptables and I want to do so in the minimal possible way both to conserve precious memory and teach myself more about netfilter in the process of fixing problems like this.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issues with my Android 2.3.3 / Linux Squeeze device and found my answer on the lefthand side of this page. Works for iptables 1.3.7.

[iptables allow all outgoing - still can't resolve dns or make a http request](https://serverfault.com/questions/339419/iptables-allow-all-outgoing-still-cant-resolve-dns-or-make-a-http-request?rq=1)

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and finally found how to correctly configure the kernel (4.18 in my case). This might be useful to others as well...

---

## Basic connection tracking support (mandatory)

First enable `CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK` so that the other options get displayed.

Then, depending on which protocol(s) you need, enable `CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV4` and/or `CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV6` (which automatically select `CONFIG_NF_DEFRAG_IPV{4,6}`).

---

## `iptables` support

`CONFIG_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK` allows OP's rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

`CONFIG_XT_MATCH_STATE` is a trimmed-down, lightweight version of `xt_conntrack` and allows the rule proposed in S0AndS0's answer:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

If you don't need the full `xt_conntrack` functionality, `xt_state` might be interesting on constrained systems due to its smaller disk size / memory footprint. Since they both use the same kernel interface in the end, I believe performance should be about the same. The key point being: does `xt_state` provide everything you need?